# Stack layout - Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have couple of labels with flexible height, they need to be positioned vertically one over another. So my question is, is there some framework or library which provides Stack Layout functionality, so i dont need to recalculate labels actual size and position? I know that maybe WebView and building html will do the job, but this is not solution because i have to add buttons and other controls between labels.

Comment: Autolayout will allow you to centre your labels and provide a fixed vertical space above one another. No calculations required on your part but you will need to use iOS6+.

Comment: If you're using autolayout (requires iOS 6), use that. Otherwise use the autosizing masks (known as "autosizing" in IB, `autoresizingMask` if done programmatically), which can keep your `UILabel`s centered on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

no,there is no such frameworks. Use `relative position`.it is very simple. simply by changing first control position you can change other control position by help of Relative positions.

just mention first control frame points & adjust other controls frame as per first control
example psudo code:

```
controlFirst.Frame= CGRectMake(10,10,50,20);
```

then

```
 controlSecond.Frame= controlFirst.Frame+10;

 controlThird.Frame= controlSecond.Frame+10;
```

Comment: Yes, relative position is what am doing in situations like this, but i was wondering if there is some more elegant way to do this. tnx anyway